# Should a samurai gain all bonus (traits and skills) when purchasing the Multiple Schools advantage?

Tags: l5r, l5r-1e

The L5R-1ed core rulebook states, in the character creation section:

> [...]Your character's training in that school will give him a few
>   bonus starting Traits and Skills.

On one hand this is pretty straightforward: training at that dojo gave you the chance to practice [bonus skills] and overall increased your [bonus trait].

On the other hand, it says "bonus **starting** Traits and Skills" which makes me suspect that these bonuses can only be gained at character creation phase.

Now, the Multiple Schools advantage allows a character to interrupt his current learning path and switch to a new school, which sparks two questions:

- Does the character gain the bonus trait and skills from the new school as well?
- If so, how do we treat bonus skill points? Two options imho:

  - bonus skill points are eventually added to existing skill ranks (e.g. a Lion bushi with a kenjutsu of 3 enters the Hida school - which gives starting Kenjutsu 1 - and gains an overall rank of 4)
  - a character only keeps the highest value between his current rank and the bonus skill points (e.g. a Lion bushi with a kenjutsu of 3 enters the Hida school - which gives starting Kenjutsu 1 - and does just keeps his rank of 3)

Thank you in advance to all who will contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You interrupt your current progress to switch to another school, its about insight and learning techniques only. So you begin with Rank 1 technique in a school, then later "in the game" you take that feat for your Rank 2 technique and beyond. It is not a character creation feat in 1st edition.

> This is an unusual advantage, in that it can only be bought after a
>   bushi (and only a bushi and only to another bushi school) has
>   progressed beyond Rank 1 in his School. GM permitting, this advantage
>   lets the player switch schools without losing his old techniques. When
>   the bushi switches schools, his old Techniques are "frozen." He won't
>   learn any further techniques from his old school, but he'll begin
>   learning new techniques in his new school immediately. As soon as he
>   gains permission to begin training at the new school, he more-or-less
>   immediately learns the Rank 1 Technique (GM's discretion on the length
>   of training necessary, but probably not longer than 3 to 6 game
>   months). The bushi then begins gaining Techniques in his new school as
>   his Insight goes up, just as usual.

Comment: Uhm..the question is whether you get the bonus traits and skills or not.

Comment: Its about insight and learning technique 'only' if you prefer :)

Comment: Ok I get your point: from a rules-as-written perspective the advantage says nothing about bonus traits/skills so you don't get them. On the other hand though the advantage doesn't say you don't get them either... this aspect is just not covered. Also, from a roleplay point of view it would make sense to actually get those bonuses, since you undergo the typical training of that school in order to learn its techniques. L5R-1ed rules have quite a lot of missing information here and there, this could be one of these cases...

Comment: Beware in the other editions, to train in another school, you need at least one point in each skill that school teach, so you won't get free skills.

Comment: Beside, in all edition its always "bonus starting Traits and Skills", it only appling for the first school you take. See this reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/rokugan/comments/27d9zi/rules_question_for_multiple_schools/